# transfer rate of dd to a disk is much less than copy file

Tags: linux, dd

The case is that I use dd command to build a bootable usb for xxOS.
/dev/disk2 is usb device.
command is

```sh
dd if=xxOS.iso of=/dev/disk2 bs=8m
```

It spends a lot of time, the transfer rate is about 2MB/s~4MB/s.
It makes me puzzle, why it's more slowly than copying files to an USB about 10MB/s or more up.
May I use the right parameter?

Comment: Because caching.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [dd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) ? You could be interested in passing `oflags=sync` and  `status=progress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assume that that the time taken for `dd` to return to the prompt is an accurate measure of the time taken to write the data to storage -- regardless of the device. Modern operating systems cache disk data in many different places. Running `dd` with the `oflags=sync` option will give a better idea of the real time, as might simply running `sync` at the prompt after the `dd` operation.

In general, though, storage I/O is pretty hard to time accurately on modern Linux systems.

Comment: In MacOS, use /dev/rdisk2 instead of /dev/disk2 will be the same.